# How to get Timezone from GMS placepicker on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, gmsmapview, gmsplacepicker, gmsplace

I'm using GMS place picker in my iOS application. It works fine. It picks the correct location but how can I get the timezone for the selected location?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372506/how-to-get-the-timezone-of-a-location-in-ios-app

Comment: Do you have latitude & longitude for the selected location?

Comment: @Glenn The provided link shows Timezone of the device's current location, but I want the Timezone of a location which is selected through GMS placepicker.

Comment: @ImadAli yes, I have the latitude & longitude of the selected location.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30528649/1025063) answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You saved my day.